# HTML DOM : How to get the whole list of registered event handlers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

For debugging purpose and memory leak, I'd like to have the full list of registered event handlers. There's this nice [visual tool](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) but a plain text list would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the mentioned link says, there is no JavaScript API to retrieve all registered listeners. So, for testing purposes you might try overriding the EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener/removeEventListener methods and storing their arguments in your own storage to inspect later.

On a similar note, you can use the Chrome Developer Tools to examine currently registered listeners for a particular node (or the node chain up to the document root) in the Elements panel ("Event Listeners" section in the sidebar.)